# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "a salto de mata"?

Tags: etimología, locuciones

Me acabo de acordar de la expresión *a salto de mata*. Hacía tiempo que no la oía y vi que el DRAE la recoge en [**salto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X79BxUq):

> [salto de mata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X79BxUq#5Gwy4Eg)
>   1. m. Huida o escape por temor al castigo.
>
> **[a salto de mata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X79BxUq#5H7LmJd)**
>   1. loc. adv. Huyendo y recatándose.
>   2. loc. adv. Aprovechando las ocasiones que depara la casualidad.

En general, en España la oigo para definir lo que se hace deprisa y corriendo:

> Me saqué la carrera **a salto de mata**: como estudiaba y trabajaba, los exámenes los aprobaba estudiando lo justo y con algo de suerte.

¿Se usa esta expresión en otras zonas aparte de España? Si es así, ¿se hace con el mismo sentido? ¿Cuál es su origen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedo sino dar una respuesta a la pregunta que pide saber su origen. Las primeras apariciones en el CORDE son del siglo XV, y siempre en refraneros:

> *Mas vale salto de mata que ruego de ombres buenos.*
>
> - Marqués de Santillana (Íñigo López de Mendoza), "Refranes que dizen las viejas tras el fuego", España (a 1454).

En el diccionario de autoridades de la RAE (tomo I, 1726) aparece recogido dicho refrán, explicándolo así:

> **Mas vale salto de mata que ruego de buenos.** Refr. que enséña, que al que ha cometido algun excesso por donde tema ser castigado, mas le aprovecha el ponerse en salvo y escaparse, que no el que pidan por él Personas de suposición y autoridad.

Luego ahí ya tenemos que el *salto de mata* es una huida para ponerse a salvo. Y curiosamente, el origen es bastante prosaico y nos lo da Covarrubias en su diccionario de 1611:

> **Saltar de la mata**, descubrirse el que estava secreto: termino de caçadores quando vã a ojeo de liebres, o conejos.

Es decir, un "salto de mata" es lo que hacen los conejos que se creen ocultos, cuando son descubiertos: saltan y huyen para ponerse a salvo en otro sitio. Como una huida se suele hacer deprisa y [a trompicones](http://dle.rae.es/?id=amIvx33), no resulta extraño que se use también con la acepción que comentas en tu ejemplo.

Sobre si se usa en otro sitio, lo más que puedo decirte es que en el diccionario de americanismos no aparece la expresión tal cual, así que o se usa con el mismo significado o no se usa, eso ya lo tendrán que decir nuestros amigos americanos.

Comment: Gran explicación como siempre, ¡gracias Carlos! No era fácil encontrar la referencia en el Covarrubias. El ejemplar que acabo de encontrar en archive.org menciona otra expresión con _matas_: _Todo lo veo matas, y por rozar, del negocio que no esta bien dispuesto, y tiene muchos inconvenientes_.

Comment: @fedorqui un placer, ya sabes que me encantan este tipo de preguntas. :-)

Answer (score 0):

En México se utiliza con el significado de huida o escape, por ejemplo: El asesino siempre vivió a salto de mata hasta que la policía lo capturó diez años después del crimen.

Answer (score 0):

Una mata es una planta boscosa amplia que bien puede usarse como escondite. Saltar de mata en mata para esconderse como el ejemplo de un conejo escondiéndose y huyendo tras ser descubierto saltaría a otra mata para refugiarse y esconderse igual que una persona huyendo de escondite en escondite